# Vectorizing a matrix with Z-order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2-dimensional square array and I would like to vectorize it following a [Z-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).
Is there an efficient way to do it?

**A little bit of context:** my matrix is an image **U** and I am averaging every 2x2 cell, to get an image that's half the size of the original one. If my image is vectorized as **v** following the Z-order, I can write this operation as **Rv** where **R** is a matrix that is much easier to write (compared to an **R'** that has to act on a **v'** that's been vectorized by a classical row-by-row order), and I need this for backing my code theoretically.

**Edit**: as my question was not sufficiently clear, I am adding a code that would perform what I want, possibly in a non-optimized way.

```
import numpy as np

def z_order(M,p):
 if p==0:
  return [M[0,0]]
 else:
  A = z_order(M[0:2**(p-1) , 0:2**(p-1)] , p-1)
  B = z_order(M[0:2**(p-1) , 2**(p-1):2**p], p-1)
  C = z_order(M[2**(p-1):2**p , 0:2**(p-1)], p-1)
  D = z_order(M[2**(p-1):2**p , 2**(p-1):2**p], p-1)
  return A+B+C+D
```

Where M is meant to be a square numpy array with side 2**p

Now, this code applied (with p=2) to

```
M = np.array([[9,8,7,6],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,0,1],
    [5,6,1,2]])
```

gives

```
[9, 8, 1, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5, 6, 0, 1, 1, 2]
```

which is the vectorized matrix according to the z-order.

Do you think my code is efficient? If not, what is the fastest way to do this that you can think of?

Comment: Can you give an example such as code that uses loops to accomplish the same function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MechanicPig thank you for replying, I added some details with code. Sorry, I thought my question was sufficiently clear, given the definitions in the wikipedia page